# Get column value from Many to Many Relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

This is my tables structure:
[image]

**Attribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model
{
   protected $guarded = [];

   public function products()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
   }

}
```

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
   protected $guarded = [];

   public function attributes()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute');
   }

}
```

I want to get the `value` column for each row.
What code should I write in my controller to access this `value`?
Laravel version:  6.9.0
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we implements [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship,it default create a intermediate table

> In your case that table is `attribute_product` table, we might reference this table as `Pivot`
>   table.

This tables value was retrieve by those model by `pivot` attribute name as follows:

```
$product = App\Product::find(1);

foreach ($product->attributes as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->pivot->product_id;
}
```

**To add Extra column in (*Pivot table*)**

By default, only the model keys [`$attribute_id`,`$product_id`] will be present on the  `attribute_product` table. If your `pivot` table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute')->withPivot('column1', 'column2','value');
```

**To change `pivot` Attribute Name to your given name**

you may wish to rename your intermediate table accessor to `values` instead of `pivot`.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute')
                ->as('values')
```

Then you will retrieve by `$attribute->values->product_id` instead of `$attribute->pivot->product_id`

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by adding the following method of your end of the relationship

```
withPivot(['value']);
```

```php
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute')->withPivot(['value']);
}
```

And also

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot(['value']);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be an array, `withPivot('value')` will do it.  Here's the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Hmm, of course, you can do it this way but when you need multiple columns.
Check this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models